# Problem recharging Soundtrap Recorder

Tags: instrumentation, troubleshooting

I have a Soundtrap ST4300 that was deployed in the marine environment for an extended period of time such that both the SD Card was full and the battery fully consumed (0% remaining). When plugged into the computer & opened in the Soundtrap Host software, I received a warning that the battery was too low and the device must be recharged for a bit before use (so, let it be and then refresh in the host software). After sitting for >1day, the device did not charge and I cannot access the data.

Are there alternative ways to charge the battery? Are there tips/tricks to preventing (or minimizing) battery deterioration? (The batteries on these devices are internal & not readily replaceable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the SoundTrap 4300 will not charge properly through the USB connection, then it may require more power than the USB to Computer connection can provide.

In this case try plugging the SoundTrap 4300 directly into a USB wall charger (ie a phone charger) and recharge the unit over night.  If you press STOP (several times, looking for red flash acknowledgement) on the remote (after plugging into the charger) this will reduce power consumption and maximize you chances of getting the battery to charge.

If the unit still doesn't hold a charge after that then the battery probably needs to be replaced and it will need to be send back to Ocean Instruments in New Zealand.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely the battery is lithium-ion.  In that case, the battery has probably been damaged from sitting at zero charge for too long, and the battery controller has disabled charging to prevent a fire or explosion.  You'll need to get the battery replaced in order to continue using the device.

In the future, you can prevent this by figuring out how long the battery is likely to last, and arrange to retrieve the recorder slightly before (or slightly after) it runs out.

Comment: It was also recommended (by John Atkins) to charge them at least every 4 months while they are in storage-- Sitting on a shelf during the pandemic is about as unhealthy for a soundtrap as sitting at a desk during a pandemic for me!